Negative search for stackoverflow.jobs
Does stackoverflow.jobs (Stack Overflow Jobs powered by Indeed) have a negative search feature?
The following do not appear to work (and actually increase the frequency of unwanted positions)

-keyword
!keyword
(not keyword)

